# Rewrite permalink to include multiple taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy, archives, rewrite-rules, regex

I've seen similar questions posted before but they don't seem to quite fit my problem.

I have a post type called product and I have 2 taxonomies, product_cat and location

I want archive pages that combine both these taxonomies which would be structured like this /product/product_cat/location

I know this can be done with rewrites but I can't figure out how to make it work.

**Update**

I've achieved this to an extent using

```
  add_rewrite_rule( '^art-classes/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
                 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&location=$matches[2]',
                 'top' );
```

But now my single product page won't load.  it just loads the archive page still.  Something wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
 add_rewrite_rule( '^art-classes/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$',
                 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&location=$matches[2]',
                 'top' );

}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

The $ at the end did the job.  Not sure why.